# How to properly attach a PageController to more than one PageView?

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a `Scaffold` with an `AppBar` installed. As the `title` for such an `AppBar`, there is a properly set `PageView` with multiple titles (that is, you can slide the title now). As the `body` for such a `Scaffold` there is another `PageView` with multiple pages where each represent a specific context.

As you can see, there are two instances of a `PageView`. Let's assume the number of children for both `PageView` is the same.

Now, let's present the question: How can I properly attach a single `PageController` to both `PageView` to control the offset of both `PageView` simultaneously?

Essentially, matching the title with the current context.

Comment: u can use a listener on PageController or ValueController and dependent on them build a title without additional PageView

Comment: @WebFox I don't like this approach because I lose the sliding effect that comes when scrolling a PageView. I like the idea of animating to a specific title instead of just spawning it.

Answer (score 0):

Used rxdart, NOT null safety, its not best way but u can try
If u dont need sync animation of swipe, this can help you:

```dart
  // define

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    subject = BehaviorSubject()..value = 0;
    final controllers = [
      titleController = PageController(),
      pageController = PageController(),
    ];
    // you can add subject.add in PageView onPageChanged and remove line "if (controller.page != 0.0 && controller.page != 1.0) return;"
    for (final controller in controllers) {
      controller.addListener(() {
        if (controller.page != 0.0 && controller.page != 1.0) return;
        final page = controller.page.toInt();
        if (subject.value == page) return;
        subject.add(page);
      });
    }
    subject.listen((int pageIndex) {
      for (final controller in controllers) {
        controller.animateToPage(
          pageIndex,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        );
      }
    });
  }

  BehaviorSubject<int> subject;

  PageController titleController;
  PageController pageController;
```